# Sort words on each line, editing the file in-place

Tags: text-processing, sed, sort

I read a file line by line and edit each line and save those lines in a separate file.

```
while read -r line
do
   newline=$(echo $line | sed -r 's/\</\n/g' | sort | tr '\n' ' ')
   echo "$newline" >> newfile
done < "$filename"
```

But I want to replace the original lines with respect to `$filename` with the new lines. I read that I could use `cat filename... | xargs -n1 command` or `sed -i ...` but till now my trails are failed.

Here is an example input:

```
1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.
1.d4 d5 2.e4 dxe4 3.
1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Nf6 3.
```

and this is the expected output:

```
 1. 2. 3. e4  e5  Nc6  Nf3  
 1. 2. 3. d4  d5  dxe4  e4  
 1. 2. 3. e4  e5  Nf3  Nf6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `sponge`, as mentioned in [A program that could buffer stdin or file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/337055/a-program-that-could-buffer-stdin-or-file/337058#337058). You can pipe the whole loop to it, in the same way the input is redirected to it:

```
while read -r line ; do 
    echo "$line" | sed -r 's/\</\n/g' | sort | tr '\n' ' ' ; 
    echo
done < filename | sponge filename
```

With Perl, the same could be done with this (the amount of whitespace is different):

```
perl -Mlocale -i -lne 'print join " ", sort split/(?<=\.)| /' filename
```

Comment: @steeldriver, ah you're quite right, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**awk** approach:

```
awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1;}{ gsub(/\./,". ", $0); split($0, w, " "); 
     asort(w);l=""; for(i in w) {l=l" "w[i]} print l}' file
```

The output:

```
1. 2. 3. e4 e5 Nc6 Nf3
1. 2. 3. d4 d5 dxe4 e4
1. 2. 3. e4 e5 Nf3 Nf6
```

---

*IGNORECASE* can be set on the command line or in a *BEGIN* rule

`split($0, w, " ");` - splits the line into separate words

`asort(w);` - sorts array values(words)

`for(i in w) {l=l" "w[i]}` - concatenating sorted words into a single line