# How to run a pipe safely and sequentially?

Tags: bash, pipe, fifo

In Linux, is it possible to run a pipe:

```
cmd1 | cmd2
```

in such a way that:

1. `cmd2` doesn't start running until `cmd1` has completely finished, and
2. If `cmd1` has an error, `cmd2` doesn't run at all and the exit status of the pipe is the exit status of `cmd1`.

To give an example, how to make this pipe:

```
false | echo ok
```

output nothing and return a non-zero status?

---

## Failed Solution 1

```
set -o pipefail
```

The pipe does have a non-zero exit status, but `cmd2` is still run even if `cmd1` fails.

## Failed Solution 2

```
cmd1 && cmd2
```

This is not a pipe. No I/O redirection.

## Failed Solution 3

```
mkfifo /tmp/fifo
cmd1 > /tmp/fifo && cmd2 < /tmp/fifo
```

It blocks.

## Suboptimal Solution

```
touch /tmp/file
cmd1 > /tmp/file && cmd2 < /tmp/file
```

This seems to be working. But it has several shortcomings:

1. It writes data to disk where I/O is slower. (Surely you can use *tmpfs* but that's an additional system requirement).
2. You have to choose the temporary filename carefully. Otherwise it can accidentally overwrite an existing file. *mktemp* may help, but an unnamed pipe saves you the naming chore entirely.
3. The filesystem on which the temporary file resides may not be big enough to hold the entire data.
4. The temporary file doesn't auto clean-up.

Comment: [Related: `sponge` and other ways of buffering stdout](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/337058/73093) (not duplicate, because of "`cmd2` doesn't start running until `cmd1` has completely finished")

Comment: @MichaelHomer `false | sponge | echo ok` would still output `ok` with a zero return value.

Comment: Why do you ask? Smells badly like some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). So please **edit your question** to improve it, give some actual motivation, and explain your use case.

Comment: With `cmd1 | cmd2`, the two processes are started concurrently, always. Synchronization between them happen _only_ through I/O, i.e. `cmd2` may want to read something and blocks until `cmd1` has outputted something.

Answer (score 4):

We don't know the size of `cmd1`'s output but pipes [have a limited buffer size](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11946/203203). Once that amount of data has been written to the pipe, any subsequent write will block until someone read the pipe (kind of your failed solution 3).

You must use a mechanism that guarantees not to block. For very large data, use a temporary file. Else, if you can afford keeping the data in memory (that was the idea after all with pipes), use this:

```
result=$(cmd1) && cmd2 < <(printf '%s' "$result")
unset result
```

Here the result of `cmd1` is stored in the variable `result`. If `cmd1` is successful, `cmd2` is executed and is fed with the data in `result`. Finally, `result` is unset to release the associated memory.

Note: formerly, I used a here-string (`<<< "$result"`) to feed `cmd2` with data but Stéphane Chazelas observed that `bash` would then create a temporary file, which you don't want.

Answers to questions in comment:

- Yes, commands can be chained *ad libitum*:

  ```
  result=$(cmd1) \
  && result=$(cmd2 < <(printf '%s' "$result")) \
  && result=$(cmd3 < <(printf '%s' "$result")) \
  ...
  && cmdN < <(printf '%s' "$result")
  unset result
  ```
- No, the above solution is not suitable for binary data because:

  1. Command substitution `$(...)` eats all trailing newlines.
  2. Behavior is unspecified for NUL characters (`\0`) in the result of a command substitution (e.g. Bash would discard them).
- Yes, to circumvent all those problems with binary data, you can use an encoder like `base64` (or `uuencode`, or a home-made one that only takes care of NUL characters and the trailing newlines):

  ```
  result=$(cmd1 > >(base64)) && cmd2 < <(printf '%s' "$result" | base64 -d)
  unset result
  ```

  Here, I had to use a process substitution (`>(...)`) in order to keep `cmd1` exit value intact.

That said, again that seems to be quite a hassle just to ensure that data are not written to disk. An intermediary temporary file is a better solution. See [Stéphane's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/388486/203203) which addresses most of your concerns about it.

Comment: Does this variable method work well with binary data? Do we need base64 or something else to prevent data corruption?

Comment: Plus, can we chain the same variable repeatedly so that we can have more commands in the pipe?

Comment: @Cyker No, null bytes would be discarded from the result.

Comment: @Cyker Answer updated

Comment: @Kusalananda, that depends on the shell, of the 5 Bourne-like shells that support that `<<<` zsh operator, NULs would be preserved in `zsh`, discarded in `bash` and `mksh` and everything past the first NUL would be lost in `ksh93` and `yash`. And in any of those shells, the trailing newlines would be lost and one would be added back by `<<<`. Also note that `<<<` is implemented with a temporary files in most. So in addition to being stored in memory, the data would also be written on the filesystem.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks. Would you know if `<<<` is implemented with temporary files in `bash`? I could check the code, but if you know...

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I'm not 100% certain, but I think Bash creates a temp file. Ok.

Comment: @Kusalananda `ls -ld /proc/self/fd/0 <<< x` on Linux gives a deleted regular temp  file in `${TMPDIR-/tmp}`

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneChazelas and Kusalananda, answer updated consequently

Answer (score 3):

The whole point of piping commands is to run them concurrently with one reading the output of the other. If you want to run them sequentially, and if we keep the plumbing metaphor, you'll need to pipe the output of the first command to a bucket (store it) and then empty the bucket into the other command.

But doing it with pipes means having two processes for the first command (the command and another process reading its output from the other end of the pipe to store in the bucket), and two for the second one (one emptying the bucket into one end of the pipe for the command to read it from the other end).

For the bucket, you'll need either memory or the file system. Memory doesn't scale well and you need the pipes. The filesystem makes much more sense. That's what `/tmp` is for. Note that the disks are likely not to ever see the data anyway as the data may not be flushed there until much later (after you remove the temp file), and even if it is, it will likely still remain in memory (cached). And when it's not, that's when the data would have been too big to fit in memory in the first place.

Note that temporary files are used all the time in shells. In most shells, here documents and here strings are implemented with temp files.

In:

```
cat << EOF
foo
EOF
```

Most shells create a tempfile, open it for writing and for reading, delete it, fill it up with `foo`, and then run `cat` with its stdin duplicated from the fd open for reading. The file is deleted even before it filled up (that gives the system a clue that it whatever is written there doesn't need to survive a power loss).

You could do the same here with:

```
tmp=$(mktemp) && {
  rm -f -- "$tmp" &&
    cmd1 >&3 3>&- 4<&- &&
    cmd2 <&4 4<&- 3>&-
} 3> "$tmp" 4< "$tmp"
```

Then, you don't have to worry about clean-up as the file is deleted from the start. No need for extra processes to get the data in and out of buckets, `cmd1` and `cmd2` do it by themselves.

If you wanted to store the output in memory, using a shell for that would not be a good idea. First shells other than `zsh` can't store arbitrary data in their variables. You'd need to use some form of encoding. And then, to pass that data around, you'd end up duplicating it in memory several times, if not writing it to disk when using a here-doc or here-string.

You could use `perl` instead for instance:

```
 perl -MPOSIX -e '
   sub status() {return WIFEXITED($?) ? WEXITSTATUS($?) : WTERMSIG($?) | 128}
   $/ = undef;
   open A, "-|", "cmd1" or die "open A: $!\n";
   $out = <A>;
   close A;
   $status = status;
   exit $status if $status != 0;

   open B, "|-", "cmd2" or die "open B: $!\n";
   print B $out;
   close B;
   exit status'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a frankly awful version stitching together different tools from [`moreutils`](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/):

```
chronic sh -c '! { echo 123 ; false ; }' | mispipe 'ifne -n false' 'ifne echo ok'
```

It still isn't quite what you want: it returns 1 in case of failure, and zero otherwise. However, it doesn't start the second command unless the first succeeded, it returns a failing or succeeding code according to whether the first command worked or not, and it doesn't use files.

The more generic version is:

```
chronic sh -c '! '"$CMD1" | mispipe 'ifne -n false' "ifne $CMD2"
```

---

This pulls together three of the moreutils tools:

- `chronic` runs a command quietly, unless it fails. In this case, we're running a shell to run your first command so that we can invert the success/failure result: it will run the command quietly *if* it fails, and print the output at the end if it succeeds.
- `mispipe` pipes two commands together, returning the exit status of the first. This is similar to the effect of `set -o pipefail`. The commands are provided as strings so that it can tell them apart.
- `ifne` runs a program if the standard input is non-empty, or if it is empty with `-n`. We're using it twice:

  - The first is `ifne -n false`. This runs `false`, and uses it as the exit code, iff the input *is empty* (meaning that `chronic` ate it, meaning that `cmd1` failed).

    When the input is not empty, it doesn't run `false`, passes the input through like `cat`, and exits 0. The output will be piped into the next command by `mispipe`.
  - The second is `ifne cmd2`. This runs `cmd2` iff the input *is non-empty*. That input is the output of `ifne -n false`, which will be non-empty exactly when the output of `chronic` was non-empty, which happens when the command succeeded.

    When the input is empty, `cmd2` never runs, and `ifne` exits zero. `mispipe` discards the exit value anyway.

---

There are (at least) two remaining flaws in this approach:

1. As mentioned, it loses the actual exit code of `cmd1`, reducing it to boolean true/false. If the exit code has meaning, that's lost. It would be possible to save the code to a file in the `sh` command, and re-load it later (`ifne -n sh -c 'read code <FILENAME ; rm -f FILENAME; exit $code'` or something) if that's necessary.
2. If `cmd1` can ever succeed with no output, everything falls apart anyway.

Plus, of course, it's multiple fairly-rare commands piped together, quoted carefully, with a non-obvious meaning.

Answer (score 1):

First off, your example `false | echo ok` is nonsensical since `false` would not output anything to its standard output and `echo` would not read from its standard input.  The "solution" to this is `false && echo ok`.

```
cmd1 && cmd2
```

This will run `cmd1` and will not start `cmd2` until `cmd1` has successfully finished executing.

In a pipeline, such as

```
cmd1 | cmd2
```

the two commands are always started concurrently (this is what you notice in your "Failed Solution 1").  The thing that synchronizes them is `cmd2` reading from the output of `cmd1`.  A pipeline is a way of passing output from one program into the input of another, concurrently running, program.

To simulate that `cmd1` is outputting something that `cmd2` reads, but to get rid of the concurrency, you would have to store the output from `cmd1` in a temporary file that `cmd2` reads:

```
cmd1 >outfile && cmd2 <outfile
```

The temporary file may be handled like this:

```
trap 'rm -f "$tmpfile"' EXIT
tmpfile=$(mktemp)

cmd1 >"$tmpfile" && cmd2 <"$tmpfile"
```

This sets up a trap that will trigger upon exiting the shell. The trap will remove the temporary file.

If you have `$TMPDIR` on a memory filesystem, you will not incur any I/O penalty for writing to disk.

If you are worried about the size of the file, then you will be forced to store it on disk no matter what (a pipe would not be able to hold the contents either, this is what you notice in your "Failed Solution 3").

---

Looking at [xhienne's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/388012/116858) for Bash:

```
result=$(cmd1) && cmd2 <<< "$result"
unset result
```

This works if the result is text that doesn't end in empty lines, but fails if it contains null bytes (these will be discarded by `bash`).

To mitigate this, we could base64-encode the result:

```
set -o pipefail # ksh/zsh/bash
result=$( cmd1 | base64 ) && base64 -d <<<"$result" | cmd2
unset result
```

This is a *terrible* idea in terms of both memory and CPU usage, especially if the result is large (the base64 encoding of `$result` will be one third bigger than the binary). You are far better off writing the binary result to disk and reading it from there.

Note too that `bash` implements `<<<` using *a temporary file* in any case.

Answer (score -1):

> run a pipe `cmd1 | cmd2` n such a way that:
>
> `cmd2` doesn't start running until `cmd1` has completely finished

This is impossible in general. Read [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) which reminds you that *pipes have limited capacity* (typically 4Kbytes or 64Kbytes) and they use some *kernel* memory for their buffer.

So the output of `cmd1` goes into the pipe. When it becomes full, any [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) done by `cmd1` to `STDOUT_FILENO` would block (unless `cmd1` is specially coded to handle non-blocking I/O to stdout, and this is very unusual) until `cmd2` has [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) from that pipe other's end. If `cmd2` did not start, that would never happen.

I strongly recommend reading a book like [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) which explains that in details (and an entire book is needed to explain all this).