# How can a command within a pipeline abort the pipeline?

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe, error-handling

Given the pipeline

```
a | b | c
```

how might I alter `b` so that it aborts the pipeline if `b` generates an error or matches a particular pattern in the input stream?

Comment: Simply have `b` terminate.

`a` will be killed by a `SIGPIPE` signal when trying to write to the left pipe, and `c` will get an EOF when trying to read from the right pipe. In `bash` (but _not_ in the shell in general), you can get the exit status of `b` from the `PIPESTATUS` array.

Comment: How do I make `b` terminate?

Comment: Call `exit` from within it. Or let it commit ritual suicide: `b(){ sed /die/q && kill "$BASHPID"; }; printf '%s\n' pass die oops | b | cat; echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"` ;-)

Comment: @mosvy, I confirmed that `b()` aborts the pipeline using the ritual suicide operation `kill "$BASHPID"` or with `exit 1`.

Comment: @mosvy, do you want to promote your comment to an answer?

Comment: @mosvy `b` terminating would not terminate the pipeline in the (very degenerate and unlikely) case where there is no actual I/O between the processes in the pipeline.

Comment: @Kusalananda in which case you can turn the job control on and kill the process group all the processes in the pipeline are part of

Comment: @mosvy, how can you determine the process group of the pipeline processes?

Comment: There's more than one way to do it. `cat | cat | pkill -g0 | cat | cat` will kill all 4 cats before them being killed by `SIGPIPE` when trying to write to pipe with no reader, or exiting with status 0 because of EOF. `ps -ho pgrp "$BASHPID"` will tell you the process group `$BASHPID` is in. You can also get the same info directly from `/proc/<pid>/stat{,us}`.

Comment: In a script (with no job control by default), you can also use a subshell to group processes for the purpose of killing them -- `bash` will always use separate processes for `(...)` subshells, and `pkill` and `pgrep` are able to find processes by their parent.

Comment: @mosvy, can you think of a way that an intermediate node in the pipeline might buffer the output and send it to final sink node `c` only if the input stream from `a` does not contain "die"?  I tried using an intermediate "sponge" that https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/337055/a-program-that-could-buffer-stdin-or-file describes following `sed /die/{q 1} || pkill -g0`, but the pipeline is subject to race conditions where sometimes it terminates and discards the input stream while other times `c` receives some input.

Comment: @mosvy, `printf '%s\n' pass die oops | { file=$(mktemp); trap "rm $file" EXIT; sed '/die/{q 1}' > $file && cat $file || exit 2; } | cat; echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}";` is an extension of your solution where node `b` in the pipeline discards the entire input stream if it encounters string "die".

Comment: Even shorter version that uses a buffer variable instead of a temporary file: `printf '%s\n' pass die oops | { input=$(sed '/die/{q 1}') && echo "$input" || exit 2; } | cat; echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}";`

Answer (score 1):

[@mosvy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/308316/mosvy)'s very helpful [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/556240/how-can-a-command-within-a-pipeline-abort-the-pipeline?noredirect=1#comment1033230_556240) was *mostly* correct, but has the problem that `b()` always aborts the pipeline whether or not `sed /die/q` encounters "die":

**Input stream contains "die"**

```
$ b(){ sed /die/q && kill "$BASHPID"; }; printf '%s\n' pass die oops | b | cat; echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
pass
die
0 143 0
```

**Input stream *does not* contain "die"**

```
$ b(){ sed /die/q && kill "$BASHPID"; }; printf '%s\n' pass oops | b | cat; echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
pass
oops
0 143 0
```

In @mosvy's version, `b()` always aborts the pipeline because `sed /die/q` returns exit code 0 (success) if it encounters "die" *or* reaches the end of the input stream and so `b()` always invokes `kill "$BASHPID"`.

In the following version, I correct @mosvy's answer so that `b()` aborts the pipeline *only* when it encounters "die" in the input stream:

**Input stream contains "die"**

```
b() {
  sed '/die/{q 2}' || kill "$BASHPID"
}

# Send "die" to b.
printf '%s\n' pass die oops | b | cat

echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
```

Output:

```
pass
die
0 2 0
```

**Input stream *does not* contain "die"**

```
b() {
  sed '/die/{q 2}' || kill "$BASHPID"
}

# Do not send "die" to b.
printf '%s\n' pass oops | b | cat

echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
```

Output:

```
pass
oops
0 0 0
```

Note that in this version of `b()`, if `sed` encounters "die", it invokes command `q 2` which causes `sed` to terminate immediately with exit code 2 (failure), and then `||` to invoke `kill "$BASHPID"` which terminates `b()`'s process in the pipeline and aborts the pipeline.  (Note that this version requires [GNU `sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) which [extends command `q`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Common-Commands.html#Common-Commands) so that it accepts an exit code.)

As @mosvy mentions, instead of committing "ritual suicide", `b()` may simply `exit` from the process:

```
b() {
  sed '/die/{q 2}' || exit 3
}

# Send "die" to b.
printf '%s\n' pass die oops | b | cat

echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
```

Output:

```
pass
die
0 3 0
```