# How do I pipe the results of a "find" or "ls" to a file AFTER it has completed its stdout?

Tags: find, pipe

So for some reason when I do something like

```
find $PWD -type f > listoffiles.txt
```

To create a list of files in current directory and save it to a list,
The file *"listoffiles.txt"* itself is somehow included in that, which tells me that it's instantiated prior to STDOUT of my pipe. How exactly can I get it to not do that?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `sponge` from MoreUtils:

```
find . -type f | sponge listoffiles.txt
```

Related:

- [A program that could buffer stdin or file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/337055/a-program-that-could-buffer-stdin-or-file)

Answer (score 1):

The output file is created before find runs. You could create it somewhere else, say:

```
$ find $PWD -type f > /tmp/listoffiles.txt
```

or `grep` it away:

```
$ find $PWD -type f | grep -v "^..listoffiles.txt" > /tmp/listoffiles.txt
```

or ask `find` to ignore it:

```
$ find $PWD -type f -not -name listoffiles.txt > /tmp/listoffiles.txt
```

Comment: upvote ... the OP posted an XY problem